# Get error with try/catch in Sequencial async functions

Tags: javascript

I have a sequence of async functions that can be resolved or rejected. This functions must be executed in the correct sequence and depend one on other. So, i used 3 async functions and a try catch block. The problem is that when I reject some of the promises in the async functions, the catch block dont get the error sended on the reject callback. How can I get the error sended on reject? (code bellow)

Or should I use promise chaining? I would like to avoid this...

```
const methods = {

methodOne: async output => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        if(error)
            reject(error) // want to get this error in try/catch block
        else 
            resolve()

        })

    })

},

methodTwo: async () => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        if(error)
            reject(error)
        else 
            resolve('output')

        })

    })

},

methodThree: async () => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        if(error)
            reject(error)
        else 
            resolve()

        })

    })

},

runMethods: async () => {

    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            await methods.methodOne()
            const output = await methods.methodTwo()
            await methods.methodThree(output)
            resolve()


        } catch(error) {

            console.log(error)
            reject(error)

        }


    })


}

}
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: "*`if(error)`*" - the `error` variable is not declared in your code, so you never reject any of your promises?

Comment: "*the catch block dont get the error sended on the reject callback.*" - actually it does, if you did reject one of the promises. Can you please provide an actual [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `try/catch`. You should use the promise `.catch` when awaiting for the methods.

You also don't need to `return new Promise (...)`.

If your promise is rejected, it will go in the `.catch` of that promise, wich is different from regular `catch`.

You could just return nested promises.

```
runMethods: () => {    
    return methods.methodOne()
            .then(() => methods.methodTwo())
            .then(output  => methods.methodThree(output))                     
}
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572), and avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Bergi That is exaclty why I added to my question `But I also don't think you need to return new Promise(...).` I also made an edit to make it more clear and how to not use `return new Promise(...).`

Comment: Thanks. Please fix it in the first snippet as well. Using `.catch(reject)` there doesn't really work since it just continues execution of the async function.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, just edited the question to make it more clear and better for understanding

Answer (score 0):

I usually come at it this way.

```js
const methods = {

    methodOne: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('method1')
                resolve()
            },1000)
           
        }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
    },
    methodTwo: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('method2')
                resolve()
            }, 1000)
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))

    },
    methodThree: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('method3')
                reject('whoops something happened')
            }, 1000)
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
},

    runMethods: () => {
        let run = new Promise(resolve=>resolve(true))
        run
            .then(result1 => methods.methodOne())
            .then(result2 => methods.methodTwo())
            .then(result3 => methods.methodThree())
            .catch(e=>console.log(e))
    }
}   

methods.runMethods()
```